# Numerically testing integrals which evaluate to Dirac delta distributions

Tags: numerical-integration, distributions

For non-distributional integrals, it is very useful that one can test integral equations numerically, e.g. if I have some argument to believe that

$$\int_0^{\infty}dx e^{-a x}=\frac{1}{a},\qquad \text{Re}[a]>0$$

then I can go to Mathematica and test the above equation using NIntegrate on the LHS for random values of $a$ and compare to the RHS for the same values of $a$ to convince myself that the above equation is correct.

Are there any tricks in order to perform a similar kind of numerical test when the expected answer is distributional? e.g. any kind of numerical test for the following equality

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d x e^{-ikx}=2\pi \delta(k)$$

which could be generalized to less trivial examples. Would be exceedingly useful!

Comment: You could multiply the integrand by a profile function such as a Gaussian with a controllable width, which would then make the Dirac delta have a finite (reciprocal) width, and so on.

Comment: This equality is not true in Mathematica: `Integrate[Exp[-I*x*k], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> k \[Element] Reals]` results in "Integrate::idiv: Integral of E^(-I k x) does not converge on {-\[Infinity],\[Infinity]}.".

Comment: This equation is an important building block for the well-known and commonly accepted Fourier analysis

Comment: @UlrichNeumann: `FourierTransform[1,k]` is defined in a complex way, not through any integral (see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Tempered_distributions_and_Fourier_transform) for info).

Comment: @user64494 No, not agreed ! Look for `The Fourier Integral and its Applications by Papoulis, Athanasios, McGraw-Hill Companies (June 1, 1962)`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
int[inf_] :=NIntegrate[1/(2 Pi) Exp[-I k x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {k, -inf, inf} ]
```

`DiracDelta[k]` only contributes in a small neighbourhood of `k==0`

```
Table[int[inf], {inf, {.001, .01, .1, 1  }}] // Quiet
(*{1. + 4.85723*10^-17 I, 1. + 1.95069*10^-11 I, 1. - 2.17519*10^-11 I,1. + 3.77816*10^-20 I}*)
```

Hope it helps!